# Как убрать опции восстановления из меню загрузки на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Как убрать опции восстановления из меню загрузки на Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поправить файл настроек grub:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

А именно, снять комментарий со строки:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
```

И обновить `grub`:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```